# Is 'why wait?' a correct usage?

Tags: grammar

I need to write a short tag line for an ad.
'Why do you have to wait?' is too long. instead can we use 'why wait?'

Comment: Personally I'd interpret "Why wait?" as "Why should you wait?", implying "Don't wait, there's no need!".

Comment: I think for the purposes of an ad tagline, the two may be synonymous. It's hard to tell without more context though.

Comment: @ash: Why wouldn't it be?  (Or, said another way, _Why not?_)

Answer (score 7):

Certainly you can. There are similar constructions such as *Why worry?*

Comment: or, _Why bother?_

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the candy bar brand Snickers has a well known ad campaign with the slogan "Hungry? Why wait?" meaning, "Are you hungry now? Why should you wait until later to eat?"